# Executing python file from another script

Tags: 14.04, python, scripts

I have a file called `main.py` and has the following code:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    print(datetime.now(),"-+- Starting")
    system('file.py')
    print(datetime.now(),"-+- Crash")
    sleep(300)
```

However, if I try to execute it from the shell using `python3 main.py` I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: file.py: not found
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    sleep(300)  # sleep for 5 minutes
```

`file.py` as well as `main.py` are both located in the same directory under `/home/username/Documents/py-script/`.

I even changed `system('file.py')` to the line below but I still can't execute `file.py`.

```
system('/home/username/Documents/py-script/file.py')
```

The program runs fine on windows, are there any additional steps I need to take in order to make it work on my Ubuntu desktop (not VM). I assigned 744 to both files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the shebang line (#! interpreter) to 'file.py'

`#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`- This will instruct to execute the file using python. Also make sure the file has enough permission to execute.

or

you should call the program with python prefix

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    print(datetime.now(),"-+- Starting")
    system('python file.py')
    print(datetime.now(),"-+- Crash")
    sleep(300)
```

Comment: Or with `/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: I forgot to mention I was adding the shebang line, but I was adding it to 'main.py'. Anyway I used `python file.py` and it ran as expected. Thanks

Comment: Glad that worked!